# Use Oauth to call yahoo api in android

Tags: android, oauth, digital-signature, yahoo-api

I want to use the Yahoo API to get login user's email in Android. I already have got access token and user GUID, but the next step to get user email is not working.

I got the following response message:

```
{oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR", realm="yahooapis.com"}
```

My code can be found [here](http://goo.gl/0pIQ8h) and the problem is documented [here](http://goo.gl/5U2w9M) at line 179.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got an answer

Full Code :

```
public class YahooScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token";
    private static final String AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL   ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token";

    static final String YAHOO_CALLBACK_URL = "YOUR_YAHOO_CALLBACK_URL";
    static final String YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY";
    static final String YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET";

    private String oAuthVerifier;

    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mainConsumer;
    CommonsHttpOAuthProvider mainProvider;

    private Button button1;
    private OnClickListener button1_onclick = new OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             new OAuthRequestTokenTask(v.getContext(),mainConsumer,mainProvider).execute();
         }
    };

    private Button button2;
    private OnClickListener button2_onclick = new OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             new OAuthGetAccessTokenTask().execute();
         }
    };

    private Button button3;
    private OnClickListener button3_onclick = new OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             getGUID();
         }
    };

    private Button button4;
    private OnClickListener button4_onclick = new OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             showToken();
         }
    };

    private Button button5;
    private OnClickListener button5_onclick = new OnClickListener()
    {
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
             getProfile();
         }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.mainConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(YAHOO_CONSUMER_KEY, YAHOO_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        this.mainProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL, AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL);
        //this.mainConsumer.setSigningStrategy(new YahooAuthorizationHeaderSigningStrategy());

        // It turns out this was the missing thing to making standard Activity launch mode work
        //this.mainProvider.setOAuth10a(true);

        // get request
        button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(button1_onclick);

        // access token
        button2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(button2_onclick);

        // guid
        button3 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(button3_onclick);

        // show token
        button4 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(button4_onclick);

        // Profile
        button5 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button5.setOnClickListener(button5_onclick);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnNewIntent - It works!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri uriData = intent.getData();
        if (uriData != null && uriData.toString().startsWith(YAHOO_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            setVerifier(uriData.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier"));
        }
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }

    class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        final String TAG = getClass().getName();
        private Context context;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private OAuthConsumer consumer;

        public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
            this.context = context;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
                final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, YAHOO_CALLBACK_URL);
                Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                context.startActivity(intent);

                return url;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute result : " + result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);

        } 
    }

    public class OAuthGetAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                mainProvider.retrieveAccessToken(mainConsumer, oAuthVerifier);
            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onPostExecute(result);
            showToken();
        }

    }

    public void setVerifier(String verifier)
    {
        this.oAuthVerifier = verifier;
//      this.webview.loadData("verifier = " + this.OAuthVerifier + "<br>", "text/html", null);
        Log.d("setVerifier", verifier);

        this.showToken();
    }

    public void showToken()
    {
        //Log.d("SubPlurkV2", "Token = " + mainConsumer.getToken() + " and secret = " + mainConsumer.getTokenSecret());
        String str = 
                "verifier = " + this.oAuthVerifier + "<br>" + 
                "Token = " + mainConsumer.getToken() + "<br>" + 
                "secret = " + mainConsumer.getTokenSecret() + "<br>" + 
                "oauth_expires_in = " + mainProvider.getResponseParameters().getFirst("oauth_expires_in") + "<br>" +
                "oauth_session_handle = " + mainProvider.getResponseParameters().getFirst("oauth_session_handle") + "<br>" +
                "oauth_authorization_expires_in = " + mainProvider.getResponseParameters().getFirst("oauth_authorization_expires_in") + "<br>" + 
                "xoauth_yahoo_guid = " + mainProvider.getResponseParameters().getFirst("xoauth_yahoo_guid") + "<br>";
        Log.i("YahooScreen", "str : " + str);
    }

    private void doGet(String url) {
        OAuthConsumer consumer = this.mainConsumer;

        final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.i("doGet","Requesting URL : " + url);
        try {
            consumer.sign(request);
            Log.i("YahooScreen", "request url : " + request.getURI());
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    try {
                        response = httpclient.execute((HttpUriRequest) request);
                        Log.i("doGet","Statusline : " + response.getStatusLine());
                        InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
                        String responeLine;
                        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        while ((responeLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            responseBuilder.append(responeLine);
                        }
                        Log.i("doGet","Response : " + responseBuilder.toString());
                        //return responseBuilder.toString();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }).start();

        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getGUID()
    {
        String GUID_URL="http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid?format=json"; 
        this.doGet(GUID_URL);
    }

    public void getProfile()
    {
        String guid = mainProvider.getResponseParameters().getFirst("xoauth_yahoo_guid");
        String url = "https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/" + guid + "/profile?format=json";
        this.doGet(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Really its awesome code snippet i had searched lot but this code solve my problem gud job many many thanks